# SQL Query for time attendance not have in out

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in my Time Attendance Database each row

```
EmpCode        Date          Time        
100            2013/10/01    08:00:00    
100            2013/10/01    08:14:12    
100            2013/10/01    12:55:11    
100            2013/10/01    13:00:00    
100            2013/10/01    16:01:00    
100            2013/10/01    16:01:05    
100            2013/10/02    16:01:00    
100            2013/10/02    16:30:45    
100            2013/10/03    08:25:00    
100            2013/10/04    08:04:00    
100            2013/10/04    15:55:00
```

I need to search time range:

1. Min(between 06:00:00 and 12:00:00) as intime
2. Max(between 13:00:00 and 22:00:00) as outtime
3. and intime must 08:05:00 if anyone come late is been show late in minute and underline intime
4. and outtime must 16:00:00 if anyone back fast is been show back in minute and underline outtime

for Example I need the results to be as follows:

```
EmpCode          Date                 intime       outtime      late      back
100              2013/10/01           08:00:00     16:01:05      
100              2013/10/02                        16:30:45     forget
100              2013/10/03           08:25:00                  20        forget
100              2013/10/04           08:04:00     15:55:00               5
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried, and what results it gave?

Comment: Consider providing date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
  EmpCode, 
  `date`,
  MIN(`time`) AS intime,
  MAX(`time`) AS outtime,
  IF(TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME('8:05:00',MIN(`time`))) < 0, 'late','not late') AS late 
FROM 
  your_table_name 
GROUP BY 
  EmpCode
```

Comment: but when i use your sql query

Answer (score 0):

result is

EmpCode          Date                 intime       outtime
100              2013/10/01           08:00:00     16:01:05
100              2013/10/02           16:30:45     16:30:45
100              2013/10/03           08:25:00     08:25:00
100              2013/10/04           08:04:00     15:55:00

it not correct when person forget to register in morning or afternoon
because MIN(`time`) AS intime,MAX(`time`) AS outtime,

if day person register only in morning the result:

EmpCode          Date                 intime       outtime
100              2013/10/03           08:25:00     08:25:00

if day person register only in afternoon the result:
EmpCode          Date                 intime       outtime
100              2013/10/02           16:30:45     16:30:45

if you can replace forget time to 00:00:00 or null

EmpCode          Date                 intime       outtime
100              2013/10/03           08:25:00     00:00:00

or

EmpCode          Date                 intime       outtime
100              2013/10/03           08:25:00

thank you very much for your question
sorry my english is bad

warat